# How to escape [ bracket while using sed command?

Tags: sed

i have one variable 
e.g.

```
var1="<envpath>/home/genl/jeenk[path]/OT/</envname>"
```

and having `<envpath>/home/genl/jeenk[path]/OT/</envname>` entry in
`file.txt`

but if i try to change this by using sed command its not changed.

e.g.

```
sed -i "s|$var1|/home/genk/g" file.txt
```

what could be the solution to this, to escape `[` `&` `]` in `var`?

Comment: `-bash-4.4$ var1=$(echo "${var1/]/\\]}")
-bash-4.4$ echo $var1
/home/genl/jeenk\[path\]/OT
-bash-4.4$ 
`  You may use both substitution for opening & closing brackets before applying to you sed command